# What code will run before construct in php？

Tags: php, extends, grpc

I am learning grpc, but I found some strange problems.

```html
<?php
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: order.proto

namespace Order;

use Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil;

class Test extends \Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message
{
    private $student_id = '';

    public function __construct($data = NULL)
    {
        echo 'test message';
        exit;
        \GPBMetadata\Order::initOnce();
        parent::__construct($data);
    }

    /**
     * Generated from protobuf field <code>string student_id = 1;</code>
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStudentId()
    {
        return $this->student_id;
    }

    /**
     * Generated from protobuf field <code>string student_id = 1;</code>
     *
     * @param string $var
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStudentId($var)
    {
        GPBUtil::checkString($var, True);
        $this->student_id = $var;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$test = new \Order\Test();
```

When I execute the above code, I can't get ‘test message’；

but, when I remove the 'extends' from class 'Test', I can got it.

what's wrong with it ? some code run before `__construct` ?

In `nginx/error.log`  I saw the following error：

74988#0: *380 kevent() reported about an closed connection (54: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: local.grpc.develop, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "local.grpc.develop"

---

I got `[1]    37548 segmentation fault` when run in cli.

Comment: are you sure you configured your development environment to show you all the errors that happens in php? (I mean `error_reporting(-1);`)

Comment: Likely your construct is throwing an error that you aren't seeing.

Comment: yes. `error_reporting = E_ALL` in php.ini. And I added `error_reporting(-1);` just now ,same error

Comment: I put the code in `try catch` ,still get 502 bad gateway

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for code formatting help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 parent::__construct($data);
```

This should be on top of your code in the construct so that the application parent construct has priority. Then your debugging should be easier. whenyou exit before the parent construct you kill the app.